# Can the static constructor be omittable in my lazy singleton class?

Tags: c#

I implement a generic singleton class as follows:

```
public sealed class Lazy<YourClass>
        where YourClass : new()
{
    static private System.Lazy<YourClass> _Instance = new System.Lazy<YourClass>();
    static public YourClass Instance
    {
            get
            {
                return _Instance.Value;
            }
    }
    
    static Lazy(){ } /*'cuz in "Instance" body, "_Instance" is accessed, so it will be initialized before being accessed, and its value will be ensured not to be null. If so, can I remove this static constructor from my code?*/

}
```

I then can use that in any other class that is intended as singleton. For example:

```
public class MySingleton{
    static public MySingleton Singleton{
          get{
             return Lazy<MySingleton>.Instance; // will this be null in some circumstances if I remove the static constructro from the above "Lazy" class?
          }
    }
}
```

If not implemented correctly, NullReferenceException might be thrown as I used to encounter. The NullReference might be the "Lazy.Instance" or the "_Instance.Value" in the "Instance" get accessor body (I'm not sure about this).

So my question is:

1. implemented as above (with the static constructor remained in the code), can I be assured that the "Instance" will never be null whenever(even in the typeInitialization of other classes) I access it?
2. can I remove the static constructor while keeping the #1 assurance?

Thanks!

Comment: Since your static constructor is empty, why do you think it has any effect on the initialization of `_Instance`?

Comment: @UnholySheep: It can have an impact on timing.

Comment: It is minor but I suggest to use other name for your own class than `Lazy`

Answer (score 3):

The static constructor isn't required to ensure that `Instance` is non-null. However, it *is* required for actual laziness to be guaranteed, in terms of type initialization.

With the static constructor in place, your type initializer (that creates an instance of `System.Lazy<T>`) won't be executed unless and until something accesses the `Instance` property within your `Lazy<T>` class. (As Peter said in comments, it would be much better to rename the class.)

Without the static constructor present, the type initializer can be executed at any time before the first field access, which means it might happen when a method which *conditionally* refers to it is JIT-compiled, even if the condition is never satisfied.

In your case, that probably won't make a significant difference, as you wouldn't access the `Lazy<T>.Value` property. But if you changed your code to create an instance of the class directly, then the static constructor is required to make sure it's genuinely lazy.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I think you are correct in pointing out that the "Intance" will surely be not null.  I used to suspect my code as I encountered some exception in debugging; after further investigation, now I suspect the issue lies with VisualStudio debugging. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814537/typeinitializationexception-inner-is-thread-being-aborted-exception-when-debu    .  I have reported this issue to visual studio team